# Count items in array where expression is true

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive

*I´m an angular newbie*

I have a directive with a template that looks something like this:

```
<div class="multiselect-styled">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link" id="link-{{ model.ControlId }}">
        <span class="options-selected" id="selected-options-{{ model.ControlId }}">TEXT</span>
        <span class="select-arrows"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

My `model` contains an array called `Options` which contains `n` number of selectable options. Each option object has a boolean property; `Selected`. I would like to replace `TEXT` with a string saying `n options selected`. So, how do I get the number of selected options?

Of course, using a loop one would do something like this but is there some way I kind bind directly to `n` in this case (Find `n` with an expression)?

```
            var n = 0;
            angular.forEach(model.Options, function(option) {
                if (option.Selected)
                    n++;
            });
```

**UPDATE 1**

Options look like this:

```
"Options": [
      {
        "Id": "ApprovedAndClosed",
        "Value": "ApprovedAndClosed",
        "Text": "ApprovedAndClosed",
        "Selected": false,
        "Code": "ApprovedAndClosed"
      },
      {
        "Id": "Cancel",
        "Value": "Cancel",
        "Text": "Cancel",
        "Selected": false,
        "Code": "Cancel"
      },
      {
        "Id": "Done",
        "Value": "Done",
        "Text": "Done",
        "Selected": false,
        "Code": "Done"
      },
      {
        "Id": "Init",
        "Value": "Init",
        "Text": "Init",
        "Selected": false,
        "Code": "Init"
      },
      {
        "Id": "ReadyForProcessing",
        "Value": "ReadyForProcessing",
        "Text": "ReadyForProcessing",
        "Selected": false,
        "Code": "ReadyForProcessing"
      },
      {
        "Id": "Rejected",
        "Value": "Rejected",
        "Text": "Rejected",
        "Selected": false,
        "Code": "Rejected"
      },
      {
        "Id": "Reminder",
        "Value": "Reminder",
        "Text": "Reminder",
        "Selected": false,
        "Code": "Reminder"
      }
]
```

Comment: Can you provide the `Options`?

Comment: Yes, updated with Options.

Comment: Is it needed to be display in the view or just in your controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

```
{{(model.Options | filter:{'Selected': true}).length}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use lodash for this:

```
var countSelected = _.filter(Options, { 'Selected': true});
console.log(countSelected.length);
```

See: [codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJyaow)